# gurobipy - unbounded model & unable to retrieve attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi

I have an assignment where I need to create a MILP model using gurobipy library. The problem is related to the Knapsack problem algorithm and I have 10 items and a specific capacity. For each item I have a low size value and a high (we do not know the exact size). We create all possible combinations for the sizes and decision variables (if the item will be included in the knapsack or not). The lists are: scenarios, revenues, decision_combs, probabilities, where scenarios is a list of 1024 list of 10 items each (all possible size combinations), the revenues is a list of 10 items where the value of each item is stored, the decision_combs is a list of 1024 lists with 10 items each with 0,1 values determining whether an item is included in the knapsack or not. Finally, the probabilities list included a probability for each scenario (list of 1024 values).

My code is the below:

```
model = gb.Model('MILP')
        obj = gb.LinExpr()

        for j, scenario in enumerate(scenarios):
            for z, decision_var in enumerate(decision_combs):
                # create model variable for scenario j and decision var vector z
                sizes = model.addVars(item_indx, vtype=gb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="sizes{}{}".format(j, z), lb=0)
                # calculate the total selected size based on the decision variables
               total_size_selected = 0
               for d, decis_var in enumerate(decision_var):
                   if decis_var == 1.0 or decis_var == 1:
                       total_size_selected += scenario[d]
                # calculate the penalty based on the capacity and selected weights
                final_penalty = penalty * (total_size_selected - capacity)
                # calculate the objective function of the current scenario and decision var vector
                obj += probabilities[j] * (sum((scenario[k] * revenues[k] * decision_var[k]) * sizes[k]
                                               for k in item_indx) - final_penalty)
                rhs = total_size_selected - capacity
                model.addConstr(lhs=gb.quicksum(sizes[k] for k in item_indx) - capacity,
                                sense=gb.GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, rhs=rhs, name="scenario{}{}".format(j, z))
                model.addConstr(lhs=gb.quicksum(sizes[k] for k in item_indx) - capacity,
                                sense=gb.GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, rhs=0, name="scenarioPositive{}{}".format(j, z))
        # set the objective function to the model
        print("Setting total objective function to model {}".format(i))
        model.setObjective(obj, gb.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
        print("Updating model {}".format(i))
        # update the model
        model.update()
        print("Optimizing model {}".format(i))
        # optimize the model
        model.optimize()

        for v in model.getVars():
            print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))
        obj = model.getObjective()
        print('Profit: %g' % -obj.getValue())
```

I have two problems with the above code. First of all, when I run the program I see in the logs that the model is not feasible or it is unbounded. So, is there something wrong with the way I have created the constraints or the objective function?

Moreover, I get an exception while trying to print the variables' values (print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))) and the objective function's value (obj.getValue()) and the error is:
unable to retrieve attribute 'x'

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model is infeasible or unbounded that means it does not return solution. `x` is the solution value that has been assigned to the variable, in both these cases since there is no solution you can't find what solution value the variable has been assigned via calling `x`.

**What to do if infeasible**

If the model is infeasible then you can [compute a model iis](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_computeiis.html) to diagnose why. This calculates the minimal set of constraints which are preventing the model from being feasible. You could do this like;

```
if model.solCount == 0:
    print("Model is infeasible")
    model.computeIIS()
    model.write("model_iis.ilp")
```

What this does is, if there are no found solutions gurobi will compute this iis and save it in a file called model_iis.ilp. You can then read this file to understand what constraints preventing a feasible solution being found.

**What to do if unbounded**

If the model is unbounded that means that the objective can increase indefinitely to infinity. [Gurobi recommends](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/optimization_status_codes.html) in this case setting the objective to 0 (or not setting it at all, this is the same thing), to determine if the model is feasible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The model is unbounded, but if I the objective is set to zero, I can get the solutions. This means that there is a problem with the objective function or with the constraints?

Comment: It means that you have variable(s) that can go to infinity to maximise your objective. In this case it looks like `sizes` has a lower bound but not an upper and are always on the greater than side of your constraints. You need to upper bound your values for sizes either via a constraint or rethinking your existing constraints or explicitly setting an ub for sizes variables, depending on what best fits your problem.

Also in your first constraint you have `- capacity` on both the lhs and rhs, these will cancel each other out.